# Normalization of quantitative phenotype in R?

Tags: r, normalization

I have a datafile with 4 columns that looks like this:

```
fid     iid     phen        sig
0002    0002    -.268465    0
0005    0005    -.033474    0
0081    0081    .2921848    0
0091    0091    1.836548    1
0094    0094    .9888859    1
0095    0095    -.1503887   0
```

The values in the 'phen' column have a leptokurtic distribution. I want to normalize the values in this column.

I read the data into R using `data <- read.table('phenfile.txt')`. I tried a few packages that will perform quantile normalization. The 'cape' package (`norm.pheno` function) gives back an error message (`dim(X) must have a positive length`) and the 'preprocessCore' package (`normalize.quantiles` function) requires a matrix as input.

Are there any other packages/functions in R that could be used to accomplish quantile normalization of a single column of values within a document?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("preprocessCore")

x <- data.frame(fid = c("0002", "0005", "0081", "0091", "0094", "0095"),
                iid =  c("0002", "0005", "0081", "0091", "0094", "0095"),
                phen = c(-.268465, -.033474, .2921848, 1.836548, .9888859,
                     -.1503887),
                sig = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0))
```

I'm not familiar with either of those packages, but

```
normalize.quantiles(as.matrix(x[,"phen", drop = FALSE]))
           [,1]
[1,] -0.2684650
[2,] -0.0334740
[3,]  0.2921848
[4,]  1.8365480
[5,]  0.9888859
[6,] -0.1503887
```

works for me. Not sure if it provides your desired standardization though.

Comment: Each column has ~800 rows, is there a way to put the values for each into data.frame other than manually entering each?

Comment: `read.table` should already create a `data.frame`. You can check by using `class(data)`. This should return `[1] "data.frame"`.